# Multiplying surds

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if I want to multiply $3\sqrt3$ with $3$, do I first do 3 * 3, and then $\sqrt3$ * 3? Or do I have to treat it like as one ?

Very elementary question, reviewing basics that I forgot. I am looking for a systematic way of doing things.

Comment: You just do $3 \times 3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that multiplication is associative, also note that $3\sqrt3=3\times\sqrt3$ 
$$3\times3\sqrt3\text{ or }3\times3\times\sqrt3\\
=(3\times3)\times\sqrt3=3\times(3\times\sqrt3)$$